# How do I use version control to make my own modifications to non vcs-ed stuff?

Tags: git, svn, command-line

Suppose I download a .vim script from somewhere that just comes "raw", it isn't in a repository anywhere.

Now I want to make a few tweaks.  But when the original author releases a new version, I'd like to easily keep my changes in there, assuming no conflicts, and if there are conflicts I'd like to know.

I am familiar with using git and svn in very simple ways, and I understand how to create my own repos if needed.

What I am really interested to know is what procedure would you go through to handle this situation?  I'm sure it's come up for you before :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab the current version from the original author.

Stick it in your version control system.

Create a branch called "vendor"

Make you own edits on the trunk, committing as you go.

When you find a new version from the original author, check out the "vendor" branch, overwrite the file(s), and commit.

Merge the vendor branch to trunk and commit.

Comment: The above (I assume) assumes git.

Comment: @nilbus: It is as much the classic CVS pattern as Git - but it depends on having a decent merge facility.

Comment: Yeah, I was actually thinking in subversion when I wrote it, but it would certainly work with git.  I don't see why it wouldn't work in CVS, though I remember very little about branching/merging in CVS.

Comment: The advantage of git being that you don't need a remote repository to track the changes anywhere.